# How to get a list of all summary messages of the Amazon Service Disruption

Tags: amazon-web-services

Amazon AWS's Summary of Service Disruption messages are a great source of insight about what not to do in Cloud or even Infrastructure and how to perform a Root Cause Analysis (RCA). Unfortunately, if you have to read all of them, you can only Google for a disruption you know has happened, and read the messages - anyone aware of how one can get a list (even better subscribe to a feed of such messages).

Comment: I initially thought you were talking about the AWS status dashboard, but you're actually talking about the post mortem analysis of events like [this one, about the EBS outage of 2011](https://aws.amazon.com/message/65648/), right?  I'm not sure this question is going to be considered on-topic here, even though it would be interesting learning material.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Exactly! These messages are a treasure trove for a "Business Continuity" researcher or a Cloud hacker